# How can i get int4range from PostgreSQL in PHP?

Tags: php, database, postgresql, type-conversion, complex-data-types

i have some convert problem in PHP core. I tried get int4range data type (like this [-1, 10)) from PostgreSQL databse v.9.5.3, to PHP dibi/row (data object from success query), I get all data correctly, but in field with int4range getiing ZERO value, not NULL. Any idea how to get int4range type to string, or some other number range format more friendly with PHP?

Thanks for answers.

BTW: I canť use POMM (Postgres Object Model Manager), cause this util is large and difficult to installation, it seems as much invasive resolution for me. I must find some native function in PHP which done it correct.

Comment: Are you using PDO or...? If PDO, I don't think it currently supports range types. You could convert to an `INT[]` or two separate `INT` columns in your SQL query, if needed.

Comment: I using, Nette DIBI layer, I guess that it originated from PDO.

Comment: dibi:
    driver: postgre
    port: 5432

This is part of config file from Nette framework

Answer (score 1):

Okay, i solve my problem by this:

```
lower(bl.storeyrange) AS min_floor,
upper(bl.storeyrange) AS max_floor
```

I split the int4range into TWO single integer values, BUT atention! int4range is discrete number ranges, and the upper value drom upper() function, select upper bound from range, BUT with this [1,7)

lower = 1

upper = 7 !!! incorrect

upper must be 6, but upper function dont recognize it.

And this solution, do not solve the problem with conversion of range types strictly in queries.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are talking about Pomm 1.x that was tedious to install. [Pomm 2.x](https://github.com/pomm-project/Foundation) core library (Foundation) is small and simple to install:

```
$ composer.phar require "pomm-project/foundation"
```

And that is all.

Once composer has done its magic your PHP file is as simple as:

```
<?php

use PommProject\Foundation\Pomm;

$loader = require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';

$pomm = new Pomm(
    [
        'my_db' =>
            [
                'dsn' => 'pgsql://user:pass@host:port/db_name'
            ]
    ]
);

$iterator = $pomm['my_db']
    ->getQueryManager()
    ->query('SELECT range_field, … ', ['parameter1', …])
    ;

if ($iterator->isEmpty()) {
    printf("No results.\n");
} else {
    foreach ($iterator as $row) {
        printf(
            "Range is from '%d' to '%d'.\n",
            $row['range_field']->start_limit,
            $row['range_field']->end_limit
        );
    }
}
```

You can even use the range as parameter in your SQL queries:

```
<?php
// …
use PommProject\Foundation\Converter\Type\NumRange;

$sql = <<<SQL
UPDATE my_table
  SET …
WHERE int_field <@ $*::int4range
RETURNING field1, …
SQL;

$iterator = $pomm['my_db']
    ->getQueryManager()
    ->query($sql, [new NumRange('[1, 42)')])
    ;
if ($iterator->isEmpty()) {
    printf("No rows updated.\n");
} else {
    foreach ($iterator as $row) {
    }
}
```

If you still think my answer is not relevant, let me know and I will delete it.